# Today's event component on partner community page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, standard-objects, partner-communities, partner

I am trying to include the Standard component to show today's events on partner community home page [Partner Central Template]. Is it possible to get that?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in my DE, it does not look like to be available for Community Home Page. Also refer to this excerpt from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_edit_pages.htm&type=5) for standard components, which says that not all components may be available for all page types.

> The Components panel lists only components that are compatible with the selected page.

You have options of either creating a custom component and adding it to your community home page or you can take a look at this [appexchange product](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EOAWsUAP), which looks like can solve your use case.